# Android build.xml got corrupted

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been on working for a while on an Android project on Eclipse.
Suddenly today when I opened Eclipse, I have seen an exclmation point near the project name, and when trying to build it, I get errors in build.xml file:

```
 <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

<!-- These targets only exist so they will be visible in IntelliJ. -->
<target name="ij-debug" depends="clean,debug"/> 
<target name="ij-release" depends="clean,release"/>
<target name="ij-install" depends="clean">
  <exec command="ant debug install"/>
</target>
<target name="ij-uninstall" depends="uninstall"/>
```

The errors are:

```
   Cannot find ${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml imported from           
   C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\projectname\android\build.xml
```

and

```
  Target clean does not exist in this project
  Target uninstall does not exist in this project
```

I have tried checking "ignore all buildfile problems", but then I get new errors:

```
Source resource does not exist:C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\projectname\android\local.properties
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

This is the folder of the project:

[image: Project Folder]

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the project, and using Android -> Fix project properties?

Comment: Yes, I did. The errors remain.

Comment: Can you provide your directory structure?  Mainly what exists in the root of your project?  Example (local.properties, project.properties, ect.).  Also are you sure the SDK path didn't get wiped out in your Eclipse settings?

Comment: Check if there are any updates to your ADT or SDK. If not, try reinstalling them.

Comment: @NicRaboy Updated my question with the folder of the project.

Comment: @babatenor I have updated today the adt, the SDK and Eclipse.

Comment: One solution I have for you, not permanent though: Remove your project from workspace, delete any files with .* extension in your project directory, restart eclipse and launch the project again.

Comment: I have just resolved it. I have deleted build.xml, then "Clean..." and built it again.
Thanks All!